# Question about formatting subscripts and superscripts for display

Tags: formatting, display

I want to display a variable with multiple subscripts (divided by commas) and a superscript surrounded by parentheses.

Namely, I want something like this:

```
rulesForDisplaying = { a[n_,i_,k_] -> _____________ }
```

where the _____ is something that will make `a[n,i,k]//rulesForDisplaying` show up as

$$ a_{n,i}^{(k)} \ \ , $$

where $n$,$i$, and $k$ can be anything.

I've tried doing something like `Superscript[Subscript[a,n,i],k]`, but there's two issues: (1) I don't know how to get artifical parentheses around k and (2) the k ends up displayed far off to the right as opposed to on top of the "n,i".

I apologize if this question has been asked before, but I haven't been able to find the relevant post.  I'm using Mathematica 10.1, if that's relevant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rulesForDisplaying[x_, n_, j_, z_] := 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(n, 
  j\), \("\<(\>" <> ToString[z] <> "\<)\>"\)]\)

rulesForDisplaying[x, n, j, z]
```

$x_{n,j}^{\text{(z)}}$

or....

```
rulesForDisplaying2[a[n_, j_, z_]] := 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(a\), \(n, 
  j\), \("\<(\>" <> ToString[z] <> "\<)\>"\)]\)

rulesForDisplaying2[a[n, j, z]]
```

$a_{n,j}^{\text{(z)}}$

Comment: Thanks!  I think that last edit did it.  :)

Comment: a little variation: `Subsuperscript[a, Row[{n, j}, ","], MatrixForm[{z}]]`

Answer (score 5):

[`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) automatically formats for display

```
Format[a[n_, i_, k_]] :=
 Subsuperscript[a,
  ToString[n] <> "," <> ToString[i],
  "(" <> ToString[k] <> ")"]

{a[n, i, j], a[1, 2, 3]}
```

[image]